# Get number of years between two timestamp objects in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I am having two `timestamp` objects.

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1800-01-01 00:00:00.0");
System.out.println(timestamp);

Timestamp ctimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(ctimestamp);
System.out.println(ctimestamp.getYear() - timestamp.getYear());
```

**Output :**

```
1800-01-01 00:00:00.0
2017-11-13 11:42:44.56
217
```

It works and gives proper value of 217. The problem here is `getYear()` is deprecated.

Is there any other way to get it, so that I don't get any deprecation warnings?

Comment: Have you tried using the calendar class, or localdate?

Comment: @dan6657, first timestamp comes from the DB. So, the above snippet is only for testing purpose. I have to create a new current time stamp to get the difference

Comment: Have you check : [Period and duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

Comment: @AxelH, I have to use timestamp only. As mentioned above, the initial timestamp comes from Database.

Comment: Why ? `Timestamp` is basicly a POJO for the ODBC. (Actually a wrapper of `java.util.Date`. But you should convert it into a `java.time.*` instance to use the new time API. You can use [`toLocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--) (Don't have time to write a full answer...)

Comment: Any reason why you are using the outdated `Timestamp` class? The modern `Instant` would be somewhat nicer to work with and would solve your problem rather easily.

Comment: @OleV.V. The database column is of timestamp type and its not in my hand to change the type.

Comment: @Yakhoob A newer JDBC driver (JDBC 4.2) or other newer means of getting data from the database will be happy to give you the timestamp from the database as an `Instant`. Which is what you should want. You have no reason to cling to the long outdated type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar`class :

```
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("1800-01-01 00:00:00.0");

    Timestamp ctimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(timestamp);

    int firstYearValue = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    calendar.setTime(ctimestamp);
    int secondYearValue = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    int diff = secondYearValue - firstYearValue;
    System.out.println(diff);
```

Comment: Let's be honest, we should not use `Calendar` as a default choice today... Check `java.time`.

Comment: I agree @AxelH, for many cases I use joda time, but here the purpose wasn't to go deeper into the java date time issues, but it was to resolve an instant case, I appreciate

Comment: `java.time` is part of the JDK since JAVA 8. This is not the Joda API. So this is an out of the box solution (see my answer for a small example of the usage).

Comment: By the way, you should get the `secondYearValue` first from the `Calendar.getInstance()` instance, since this return a `Calendar` for the current time. Don't need to use the second instance of `Timestamp` and don't need to use `setTime` twice.

Comment: yeah you are right, but I suppose the general case where the second value is not forced to be the current date, I mean the current year

Answer (score 4):

## API java.time

We can easily convert a  [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) into a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using [`Timestamp.toLocalDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--).

From that [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), we can extract the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) using [`LocalDateTime.toLocalDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate--).

Now that we have a `LocalDate`, we can use a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html). A complete explanation is available on Oracle : [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1800-01-01 00:00:00.0");
java.time.LocalDate lDate = timestamp.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();

java.time.Period prd = java.time.Period.between(lDate, java.time.LocalDate.now());

System.out.println("Years : " + prd.getYears());
System.out.println("Month : " + prd.getMonths());
System.out.println("Days : " + prd.getDays());
```

And here you have on today date (2017-11-13)

```
Years : 217
Month : 10
Days : 12
```

As suggested by [*Ole V.V*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v), if you only need a specific field, you can use [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) like :

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(
        timestamp.toLocalDateTime(), 
        java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
)
```

Note : I used absolute path here for my classes, if this is shocking, please let me know, I will clean this to be more readable.

Comment: More appreciation for this.

Comment: Upvoted for the good recommendation of `java.time`. If the OP is only interested in years (not months), it may be simpler to use `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(Timestamp.valueOf("1800-01-01 00:00:00.0").toLocalDateTime(), LocalDateTime.now())`. And even better to retrieve the data from the database into an instance of a modern class (either `LocalDateTime` or `Instant`) and drop using the outdated `Timestamp` class completely.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your feedback. I did include a more complete example than necessary, I have included the shorter one with `ChronoUnit` too. For the second part (don't use `Timestamp` at all) I preferred not to start on that path, I didn't had the opportunity to check what is supported yet so I am not sure of what is possible exactly.